# Is there a language implemented as a neuron network?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Does there exist some language whose execution model is implemented as a neuron network, or maybe as some other type of a network/grid (e.g. network of finite automata)? That is, specifically, without a central execution supervisor and main loop function, but where the execution point is moving from one node to another?

Comment: I think there's an issue with this question is that the language and it's execution model are two (generally) independent things.  I get where you are going and I think it's interesting but you will probably get better answers by reformulating your question.

Comment: Some kind of looping or recursion is strictly necessary to achieve Turing completeness. This may be achievable with a recurrent neural network architecture. However, NNs are inherently parallel, and it does not make sense to speak of an “execution point” that is “moving” between nodes.

Comment: Natural languages are implemented as neuron networks…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the 1980s to '90s, there was something like what you have described.

The Inmos Transputer was a processor designed to run multiple parallel tasks, and the occam2 language was created to run on them.  Tasks communicated via message channels, and never by modifying shared memory.

Each Transputer had a number (usually four) of high speed serial ports.  So Transputers could be connected together in mesh networks.  Tasks on the individual processors could then use the serial ports for their message channels, though a significant limitation was that one physical serial link could only carry one message channel in each direction.  More sophisticated routing was left to the programmer to implement.

occam2 was heavily based on the concept of "communicating sequential processes".  It was a significant break from the usual method of multi-tasking and multi-threading, which uses shared memory as the communication method.

Comment: Arguably this is still a common design paradigm in supercomputing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface being the standard framework, but operating over more complex network protocols like infiniband or ethernet.

Comment: Why I asked this question is that the main bottleneck in interpretive languages, as I see it, is the main loop. My hypotheses was that if you divide the computation task (the program) on several smaller ones, and assign them to several relatively independent communicating computing agents, then one can get rid of the main loop and from a big chunk of interpretive overhead. I was wondering if such idea had already been tried, because it seems to realy work: https://transd.org

Comment: The funny thing is the concidence in the prefix "trans".